# Unable to return list of object from Future

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am performing a firebase query and I want to return a list of object afect going though my for loop.But the process stoped in for loop and doesn't return anything.I am also using get package to show data at screen after casting the furture function into stream data.

Now I want to know how to well return  this list inside Future function.Thank you very much if you can tell me how.

```
Future<List<InfoCompagnie>> fetchCompanies(
    String depart, String arrivee, String jour, int place) async {
  var firstCaseDate = jour.inCaps;
  var codedDepart = depart.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
  var codedArrivee = arrivee.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
  List<InfoCompagnie> compagnieList = List<InfoCompagnie>();

  await db
      .collection('DISPONIBILITE')
      .document('FzxJ0eta1xIcSFyxd9nE')
      .get()
      .then((DocumentSnapshot event) {
    for (var compagnie in event.data[firstCaseDate]) {
      db
          .collection('PLACE')
          .document(compagnie)
          .collection('$codedDepart-$codedArrivee')
          .document(firstCaseDate)
          .collection('Bus')
          .where('PlaceDisponible', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
          .getDocuments()
          .then((QuerySnapshot event) {
        if (event.documents.length > 0) {
          for (var data in event.documents) {
            var infoCompagnie = InfoCompagnie().obs;
            //Obtention du nomble de place disponible pour le voyage ici
            accessiblePlace = data.data['PlaceDisponible'];
            codeBus = data.data['CodeBus'];
            infoCompagnie.update((value) {
              value.accessiblePlace = accessiblePlace;
            });

            //Obtention de la classe du bus de voyage ici;
            db
                .collection('VEHICULE')
                .where('CodeBus', isEqualTo: codeBus)
                .getDocuments()
                .then((QuerySnapshot event) {
              for (var data in event.documents) {
                classe = data.data['Classe'];
                infoCompagnie.update((value) {
                  value.classe = classe;
                });
              }
            });

            //Obtention des info de la compagnie ici compagnie ici
            db
                .collection('COMPAGNIE')
                .where('Code', isEqualTo: compagnie)
                .getDocuments()
                .then((QuerySnapshot event) {
              for (var data in event.documents) {
                companieName = data.data['Nom'];
                companieCode = compagnie;
                infoCompagnie.update((value) async {
                  value.companieName = companieName;
                  value.companieCode = companieCode;
                  value.travelNumber = getTravelNumber(companieCode);
                });
              }
            });

            //Obtention de l'horaire de voyage ici
            db
                .collection('PLACE')
                .document(compagnie)
                .collection('$codedDepart-$codedArrivee')
                .getDocuments()
                .then((element) {
              for (var data in element.documents) {
                //Obtention du montant du ticket de voyage ici
                if (data.documentID == 'Montant') {
                  amount = data.data['Montant'];
                  infoCompagnie.update((value) {
                    value.amount = amount;
                  });
                } else if (data.documentID == 'Horaire') {
                  infoCompagnie.update((value) {
                    //Obtention de l'horaire de voyage ici
                    value.departureHoure = data.data['HeureDépart'];
                    value.arrivalHoure = data.data['HeureArrivée'];
                  });
                } else {
                  var days = {
                    'Lundi',
                    'Mardi',
                    'Mercredi',
                    'Jeudi',
                    'Vendredi',
                    'Samedi',
                    'Dimanche'
                  };
                  if (days.contains(data.documentID)) {
                    db
                        .collection('PLACE')
                        .document(compagnie)
                        .collection('$codedDepart-$codedArrivee')
                        .document(data.documentID)
                        .collection('Bus')
                        .where('PlaceDisponible', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
                        .getDocuments()
                        .then((bus) {
                      if (bus.documents.length > 0) {
                        for (var busInfo in bus.documents) {
                          infoCompagnie.update((value) {
                            value.othersPlaces[data.documentID] =
                                busInfo.data['PlaceDisponible'];
                          });
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  }
                }
              }
            });
            compagnieList.add(infoCompagnie.value); //Adding to list here
          } //Fin for de compagnie
        } //Sortie de condition if
      });
    } //Fin for
  });
  return compagnieList; //Return my list here
}
```

Comment: Ouf c’est dûr à lire. I suggest that you use await instead of chaining the .then(). It makes the code much more readable imo.

Comment: @lenz Ahah Merci.I used await and I got only data form one dcoument insted of a list

Comment: I suggest you do as @lenz says and update your code to use `await` instead of `then`. The latter doesn't cause the code to stop, so if you are expecting to update `infoCompagnie` inside a `then` statement without awaiting it, the object will be added to `compagnieList` without being updated (probably). Modify the code to use `await` statements instead of `then` and update the question.

Comment: Thank you @Ajordat.I updated my code using Stream instead of Future. but I will ask a new question